# How can I convert this to a JSON file where the data that I enter in the textfield goes into the JSON and to firebase?

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to covert my code to a JSON format. I don't know how to get the data on the textfields using JSON.

This is a web app that I'm trying to do that can save data to firebase realtime database, and I don't know how will I be able to get the data on the fieldbox to JSON.

```
<script>
    function getInfo() {
    var firstName = document.getElementById("firstName");
    var lastName = document.getElementById("lastName");
    var cPhone = document.getElementById("cPhone");
    var exampleInputEmail1 = document.getElementById("exampleInputEmail1");
    var Bday = document.getElementById("Bday");
    var inputGender = document.getElementById("inputGender");
    var inputAddress = document.getElementById("inputAddress");
    var City = document.getElementById("inputCity");
    var inputState = document.getElementById("inputState")
    var inputZip = document.getElementById("inputZip");
    var inputMessage = document.getElementById("inputMessage");
    var Clinic = document.getElementById('Clinic').value;
    window.alert("Appointment Request Sent! Please wait for a confirmation on your Email or We'll txt you back!")
    var firebaseRef = firebase.database().ref();
    var fname = firstName.value;

    firebaseRef.child("FirstName").set(fname);
    var lname = lastName.value;

    firebaseRef.child("LastName").set(lname);
    var cp = cPhone.value;
    firebaseRef.child("Contact").set(cp);
    var gender = inputGender.value;
    firebaseRef.child("Gender").set(gender);
    var bday = Bday.value;
    firebaseRef.child("Birthdate").set(bday);
    var address = inputAddress.value;
    firebaseRef.child("Address").set(address);
    var city = City.value;
    firebaseRef.child("City").set(city);
    var state = inputState.value;
    firebaseRef.child("Province").set(state);
    var zip = inputZip.value;
    firebaseRef.child("Zip").set(zip);
    var email = exampleInputEmail1.value;
    firebaseRef.child("Email").set(email);
    var message = inputMessage.value;
    firebaseRef.child("Message").set(message);
    var cl = Clinic.value;
    firebaseRef.child("Clinic").set(cl);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to send the data to Firebase with one call, you can pass it all in a single JSON object like this:

```
let value = {
  FirstName: firstName.value,
  LastName: lastName.value,
  Contact: cPhone.value,
  Gender: inputGender.value;,
  Birthdate: Bday.value,
  Address: inputAddress.value,
  City: City.value,
  Province: inputState.value,
  Zip: inputZip.value,
  Email: exampleInputEmail1.value,
  Message: inputMessage.value,
  Clinic: Clinic.value
};

var firebaseRef = firebase.database().ref();
firebaseRef.set(value);
```

Note that you're currently always overwriting the previous data in `firebaseRef`. To add a new child node each time you submit, use `push()`:

```
firebaseRef.push(value);
```